# Django handle transaction on filter query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a **Model** that has a "**score**" attribute and a route that returns the object with the **biggest score** from the database (MySQL).

I want to use multiple instances of the same application (two microservices) and I am afraid that I will face race conditions, both machines returning the same client. How could I make sure that this is not happening?
After returning a client, it will be marked as PROCESSED.

```
def getClient(request):
    client = Client.objects.order_by('-score').filter(state="UNPROCESSED").first()
    client.state = "PROCESSED"
    client.save()
    return HttpResponse(f"<h1>{client.name}</h1>")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official document, the transaction processing is well described.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/